# What is the eetop field on Thread for?

Tags: java

I can find no documentation and only [the following discussion](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1169115) which is not very clear on what it's for.

Comment: Not sure how this question is "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered" it's pretty specific... Is it wrong to have an interest in JVM/JDK internals?

Comment: In case you wonder, like I did, what is the answer... please vote to re-open. I can answer it now but not while it's closed...

Comment: Your post is now reopened. Unfortunately, I answered it before I have read your comment :-)

Comment: Not a problem :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: JDK1.1 and before had a `privateInfo_offset` field which was used
>   for the platform thread structure, and a eetop offset which was used
>   for thread local storage (and unused by the HotSpot VM). In JDK1.2 the
>   two structures merged, so in the HotSpot VM we just use the eetop
>   field for the thread instead of the `privateInfo_offset`.

It the JRE source, it is a pointer to the underlying OS-level native thread instance of the JVM ([ref](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2013-June/011407.html)). In the latest JDK source, the file `hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/javaClasses.cpp` still contains the field, and also the comment is there.

In the corresponding java class, (`jdk/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java`), it is declared as `private long` (probably because Java doesn't know pointers).

Comment: Just checked JDK 1.8.0_60, the field is still in the `Thread` class. It also doesn't follow from the quotation that it was removed, it only says that `privateInfo_offset` was merged into `eetop`.

Comment: @AndrewLygin Wow! I've checked only the docs, and not the JRE sources. It is quite interesting, investigation on the way. I'll be back soon!

Comment: It contains the reference to the native `JavaThread` structure that is still used by the VM internally. So, the quotation is correct, you just need to revise your conclusion.

Comment: @AndrewLygin Done. Thanks :-)

Comment: I would change *thread-local storage of the JVM* to *reference to the native thread*. Please, have a look at this response on Concurrency Interest: http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2013-June/011407.html. The term *thread-local storage* might confuse someone because there's another field `Thread.threadLocals` that has a different purpose.

Comment: @AndrewLygin And now?

Comment: It's closer now, but it's still not completely correct. But that's my fault, because I didn't say that it's not the OS native thread reference. It's the reference to a VM native (c++) structure called `JavaThread`. So, please, change '*OS-level native thread instance of the JVM*' to '*VM native thread structure*' and that will be correct.